# Android Gallery - Multiple Images - Pre-selected images

Tags: android, gallery, android-gallery

I need to allow a person to upload multiple images in my app. So I open the gallery like so -

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setType("image/*");
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
         startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), REQUEST_GALLERYPICK);
```

And handle the URIs returned like this -

```
 if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                    ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                    mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                        ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                        Uri uri = item.getUri();
                        mArrayUri.add(uri);
                    }
                }
```

So I have a list of URIs that the user had selected and I can display bitmap-thumbnails of the same in the activity.

The problem is, I have an "Add More Photos" button which should open the gallery again but **the photos he selected last time should already be ticked**.

How do I implement this pre-selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. There is no means to tell an arbitrary third-party app "please pre-select these images".

Comment: Any idea how the apps which allow photo upload like whatsapp or facebook do it? They use a custom gallery then? I was hoping to avoid building an image-picker from scratch.

Comment: You need to create a custom gallery for this

Comment: @Mallika: There are [a dozen or so image-picker libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/157). Whether any of them support what you want, I cannot say. Also, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` can pull in content from other apps (Google Drive, Dropbox, etc.) that you cannot access directly. I would strongly recommend that you reconsider your UI and eliminate the "pre-select these images" bit.